# Basic authorization fails when using Flurl

Tags: authorization, flurl

In an api demo, WebClient authenticates correctly when set like this

```
client.Headers["authorization"] = $"Basic Njk4NzYzNTc6dGVzdHBhc3N3b33JkX0RFTU9QUklWQVRFS0VZMjNHNDQ3NXpYWlEyVUE1eDdN";
```

Using Flurl.Http 3.0.4, all the following fail with "invalid login or private key"

```
await url.WithOAuthBearerToken("Njk4NzYzNTc6dGVzdHBhc3N3b3JkX0RFTU9QUklWQVRFS0VZMjNHNDQ3NXpYWlEyVUE1eDdN").GetJsonAsync();
await url.WithOAuthBearerToken("Basic Njk4NzYzNTc6dGVzdHBhc3N3b33JkX0RFTU9QUklWQVRFS0VZMjNHNDQ3NXpYWlEyVUE1eDdN").GetJsonAsync();
await url.WithHeader("authorization", "Njk4NzYzNTc6dGVzdHBhc3N3b33JkX0RFTU9QUklWQVRFS0VZMjNHNDQ3NXpYWlEyVUE1eDdN").GetJsonAsync();
await url.WithHeader("authorization", "Basic Njk4NzYzNTc6dGVzdHBhc3N3b3JkX0RFT3U9QUklWQVRFS0VZMjNHNDQ3NXpYWlEyVUE1eDdN").GetJsonAsync();
```

How do I implement the authorization demonstrated when using Flurl?

Comment: it might be the key from the demo does not work anymore, maybe you have to get your own credentials

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Matthias but the token remains valid

Comment: The last one looks the most correct. Try capitalizing "Authorization". Header names shouldn't be case-sensitive, but that's assuming the server implements the spec correctly.

Comment: The demo works with lower case authorization so case is not the issue